# Möbius band in $S^1 \times RP^3$ or the fibration of $RP^3$ over $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, projective-space, fiber-bundles

In $M^4=S^1 \times RP^3$ with a real projective space $RP^3$, could we construct a Möbius band M$^2$ which is a nontrivial line bundle over $S^1$ such that:

- this Möbius band  M$^2$ is embedded in  $M^4=S^1 \times RP^3$, and
- this Möbius band  M$^2$ shares the same $S^1$ of $M^4$?

If yes, the  Möbius band M$^2$ can be embedded in $M^4=S^1 \times RP^3$, then it seems strange because the $M^4$ is a trivial bundle $RP^3$ over $S^1$. Could you explain why this still a yes construction?

If no, could we find another 4-manifold $N^4$ (also with a $S^1$ circle) such that the  Möbius band M$^2$ is embedded in $N^4$? For example,  should $N^4 = S^1 \ltimes RP^3$ and M$^2 = S^1 \ltimes I^1$? (what exactly is this fibration construction?)

Comment: 1. Is this homework...? 2. If you replace $S^1 \times RP^3$ with $S^1 \times B$ ($B$ an open $3$-ball) does that help?

Comment: No this is not a homework. I am just trying it for fun. I require 1× with B cannot have a boundary. So B cannot be an open ball. I only allow a closed 4-manifold.

Comment: Thanks again for comment -!

Comment: Hint: You can embed $M^2$ in $B^2\times S^1$ so that $0\times S^1$ is the middle circle of the Moebius band.